# Почему PHP рандом генерирует строки с одинаковыми символами?

Tags: php, случайные-числа

форумчане!

Никогда раньше такого не замечал, но вдруг столкнулся с проблемой повторяющихся символов в рандомно сгенерированной строке. Код:

```
$input = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$input_length = strlen($input);
$random_string = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $random_character = $input[rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
    $random_string .= $random_character;
}

return $random_string;
```

И в итоге получаю такой результат из 10 строк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня даже при нежелании не получилось не заметить, что символы повторяются в строке по нескольку раз.

Почему так происходит ?

Comment: А зачем тут str_shuffle? Или, если уж использовать shuffle, то можно просто взять первые 6 символов без цикла.

Comment: Хотя сам по себе результат конечно любопытный…

Comment: Да, кода тут, конечно, прям дофига для такой простой функции. А так, объяснение скорее всего кроется в попытке PHP оптимизировать ресурсы. Но это прям странно.

Comment: У меня на PHP 7.4.3 не воспроизводится. (Но в любом случае имейте в виду, что rand() нельзя использовать для вещей, связанных с безопасностью)

Comment: Это уже я пытался шафлом разбавить рандом, но итог все равно одинаковый

Comment: Спасибо за предостережение) Это создание промо-кодов, их можно в принципе оставить и в таком варианте, но все равно странно...

Comment: FV1Z1F
K94KK0
5442F5
TMEQMM
ZV555V
TT2TA8
EMAPMM
2229G6
XEWCCP
RXRVSR

Следующая партия

Comment: NN8888
1N6NER
2NZN4N
SKSSWG
BBNNT9
IMIIMM
AA6H6A
A9EW9X
EEFATE
BN6NN9

И еще в догонку.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar объяснения там не в ресурсах, а в направлении того, что rand это псевдослучайные числа. и алгоритм при запуске с одинаковым начальным $seed будет/может давать одинаковые последовательности.

Comment: @teran тем не менее в такой ситуации это не должно проявляться (и у меня не проявляется)

Comment: @andreymal проверить бы на разных версиях и платформах. там есть какое-то примечание по поводу 7.2х64

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь в конфигурации сервера, но на данный момент - PHP Version 7.2.34-18+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Проверил на другом 7.2.32 -  все отлично и очень рандомно.

Comment: @RobertCody Если str_shuffle не влияет на результат, то уберите его, чтобы не путать читателя. Входящую строку тоже продублировали для большей рандомности? Постарайтесь свести код к минимальному, демонстрирующему проблему. Изолируйте его от остального приложения. Сохраняется ли при этом проблема?

Comment: @RobertCody подозреваю, что у вас опечатка в проблемном коде, а в коде для so опечатки нет. Как тестируете? На разных php выполняли один и тот же код?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Ок, поправил. Опечатки нет, код скопировал на другой сервер с другой конфигурацией и проблем там не наблюдаю. Код изолирован отдельным файлом без примесей - как есть.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин поправка, код не изолирован, используется общем контроллере с присутствием токена, если это как-то влияет

Comment: @RobertCody не знаю что за токен, но очень даже может влиять. Чтобы изолировать проблему можно написать простенький скрипт с вашим кодом и посмотреть на результат. Если проблема останется, значит она в исследуемом фрагменте. Дальше можно подебажить:  с какими аргументами вызывается и что выдаёт рандом на каждой итерации?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин отправил код в корень отдельно - все отлично. Токен авторизации. Это все выполнялось в админке Opencart.

Comment: @RobertCody то есть в изолированном варианте странное поведение rand не наблюдается и всё работает как надо? Если так, то закрывайте вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код верный, но использование его внутри админ контроллера в Opencart дает предвзятые результаты. Возможно дело в формировании токена. Посему, вопрос закрыт. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Гипотеза: проблемный код отличается от опубликованного.

Судя по результатам, вы делаете шафл строки, а потом в цикле выбираете только из нескольких 4-5 первых символов. Например так:

```php
function badRandom() {
    $input = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $shuffled = str_shuffle($input);
    $input_length = strlen(input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $random_character = $shuffled[rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }

    return $random_string;
}
```